# Process name change at runtime (C++)

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it possible to change the name(the one that apears under 'processes' in Task Manager) of a process at runtime in win32? I want the program to be able to change it's own name, not other program's. Help would be appreciated, preferably in C++. And to dispel any thoughts of viruses, no this isn't a virus, yes I know what I'm doing, it's for my own use.

Comment: you aren't writing a virus, are you?

Comment: @xtofl: If he wanted to do that, it would be just as easy, and more effective, to change the name in the exe of the virus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you're asking for Win32, but under most *nixes, this can be accomplished by just changing argv[0]

Comment: Sorry, what's argv? and a *nix?

Comment: By *nix, I mean most of the various Unix variants, Linux, FreeBSD and the such.  argv is the name of the variable used to hold the command line in a unix shell, it's an array of strings where argv[0] refers to the name the program

Comment: I won't claim this for most Unix variants, but on Linux > 2.6.9 the right way to do this is to use prctl, specifically PR_SET_NAME.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to submit what i believe IS a valid reason for changing the process name at runtime:

I have an exe that runs continuously on a server -- though it is not a service.  Several instances of this process can run on the server.  The process is a scheduling system.  An instance of the process runs for each line that is being scheduled, monitored and controlled.  Imagine a factory with 7 lines to be scheduled.  Main Assembly line, 3 sub assembly lines, and 3 machining lines.

Rather than see sched.exe 7 times in task manager, it would be more helpful to see:
sched-main
sched-sub1
sched-sub2
sched-sub3
sched-mach1
sched-mach2
sched-mach3

This would be much more helpful to the Administrator ( the user in this situation should never see task manager).  If one process is hung, the Administrator can easily know which one to kill and restart.

Comment: This is valid for any interpreted language, perl or python scripts, batch files, java processes, even javascript running in node will run into this issue.  Several of these have their own ways to do this, you can search for solutions for batch files and python for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I found [code](https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=66443&lngWId=1) for doing that in VB. I believe it won't be too hard to convert it to C++ code.

A good book about *low level* stuff is [Microsoft Windows Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619174).

And I agree with Peter Ruderman

> This is not something you should do.

Comment: This just hacks into the Task Manager - this is clearly a dangerous solution.